# Find $\limsup\left(\frac{\sin n}{n}+\cos\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

Find $\limsup\left(\frac{\sin n}{n}+\cos\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)$. The hint is that let $a_n=\frac{\sin n}{n}+\cos\frac{\pi n}{3}$, so there are six sub-sequences. I don't really get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is my attempt:

Let $n_k= 6k+b$, for $0\leq b\leq5$. Then:

$\lim a_{n_k}$ $=$ $\lim \frac{sin(6k+b)}{6k+b}+cos\frac{\pi b}{3}=cos\frac{\pi b}{3}$, then the set of sequential limits of $a_n$, denoted by $S$, contains $\frac{-1}{2},1,-1,\frac{1}{2}$, so $\lim\sup a_n = \sup S = 1$. Is that correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Hint: $sin$ is bounded and $cos$ is $2\pi$-periodic